# Can I replace casper-rw file from another live usb to have its content copied?

Tags: usb, transfer

I have a live ubuntu 16.01.1 usb A and B
I would like to copy the contents of A to B
Is it convenient to just copy and replace the file from A to B.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? About what kind of "contents" are you talking?

Comment: Sounds pretty simple to me, the op wants to copy the casper-rw persistence file from one persistent install on USB A, to another install on USB B. This has uses such as backup and sharing persistent installs. A search on Google does not mention this. Software can be installed and shared without transferring the whole install. This is a good question.

Comment: I just wanted to have a backup of my live usb to try sth that could crash or remove most of my data in my installed live usb. But anyway thanks. Replacing casper-rw worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a *casper-rw* file or partition has always worked for me.

You have to make sure that the word **persistence** is included in *txt.cfg* for an install made with Startup Disk Creator or in syslinux.cfg for an install made with UNetbootin.

For a grub2 type install made with **mkusb** the word persistence should be located in *grub.cfg*.

You can place the word persistence on the kernel line one space after --.

The following is similar for each case:

```
 linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso splash -- persistent
```

You can not **reuse** the casper-rw file or partition in an upgrade of Ubuntu.
You can reuse a home-rw file or partition after an upgrade.

If you are using *mkusb* as the installer you can even *place* the persistence partition on your hard drives root or on a second flash drive with a partition formatted ext2 or ext4 and *labeled* **casper-rw**.

You can copy and paste a persistent partition using **gparted**.

Backing up persistent partitions should be done with **dd** or **mkusb** which puts a layer of safety around **dd**. Clonezilla is even a better choice as it ignores empty space.

These preserve the partition's UUID so that programs such as VBox do not require re-installation.

Comment: Please add a simple of the makeusb opción que recheck for typos